# Contract-First or Code-First?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wso2, apache-axis, axis

Which approach (Contract-First/Code-First) should be used when creating Web services with Apache Axis2? If I choose the contract-first approach, which tool should I use to create wsdl? I am using the WSO2 platform.

Answer (score 8):

Contract-first is the best approach IMHO. The reason is quite simple. When you code first and generate a WSDL, it might change. This may cause problems for other teams working on client code based on that WSDL.
In case of contract first, the WSDL will always be the subject of discussion between teams, and it will not just change because of code changes, but only when all parties agree.
It is best to use versioning in it as well.

You can create a WSDL in Eclipse, which also has excellent checks (requires internet access).

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. This is not about Axis2 or WSO2 only .. its about the right way to think about services. Contract first means you're starting by thinking about the API your service consumer is going to use. Getting the API designed right means you can keep that away from implementation details and implementation influences.

Answer (score 1):

Definitlety contract first. 
Interfaces are the way to go for strong typed web services.